# Unknown: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 329 openCart

Tags: php, opencart

opencart выходит такая ошибка вверху страницы. Вот строка

```
            $modFilePath = preg_replace('/([^*]+)/e', 'preg_quote("$1", "~")', $modFilePath);
```

Comment: А opencart не обновляют что ли? С версии PHP 5.5.0, если передается модификатор "\e", вызывается ошибка уровня E_DEPRECATED. С версии PHP 7.0.0 в этом случае выдается E_WARNING и сам модификатор игнорируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените функцию preg_replace() на [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) так

```
$modFilePath = preg_replace_callback(
    '/([^*]+)/', 
    function($match) { return preg_quote($match[1], "~"); },   
    $modFilePath
);
```